# why my selection sort is not swapping values?

Tags: c

This code is not giving any syntax error but is has some logical error and it seems the program is working before `swap` function and the values are not swapping while running the program the output window freezes. Please help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *a, char *b);  //function to swap strings

int main() {
    char *fruits[] = { "lemon", "grapes", "water melon" };
    char minstr[15];
    int min_ind;
    int c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        strcpy(minstr, fruits[i]); //copies the ith value into minstr array from fruits array 
        printf("%s\n", minstr);
        min_ind = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) {
            c = (strcmp(fruits[j], minstr));
            printf("value of c is %d\n", c);
            if (c < 0) 
                min_ind = j;
            printf("value of min ind %d\n",min_ind);
        }
        if (min_ind != i)
            swap(minstr, *(fruits + i));
    }
    printf("the sorted aray is:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        printf("%s\n", fruits[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(a) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(temp, a);
 `  strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, temp);
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step through it examining control flow and variable values as it runs.

Comment: The `fruits` array contains pointers to string literals. It is Undefined Behaviour to attempt to write to string literals which is what the `swap` function does. Instead, you should pass in the whole array and indices to swap and then move the pointers around in the arrray instead of using `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not swap the string pointers, it attempts to swap thestring contents. This assumes both strings point to `char` that are large enough to accommodate the new strings and that are modifiable.  This is not the case of the string literals you intialize `fruits` with.

You should just swap the pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *fruits[] = { "lemon", "grapes", "water melon" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int min_ind = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) {
            int c = strcmp(fruits[j], fruits[i]);
            printf("value of c is %d\n", c);
            if (c < 0) 
                min_ind = j;
            printf("value of min ind %d\n", min_ind);
        }
        if (min_ind != i) {
            const char *temp = fruits[i];
            fruits[i] = fruits[j];
            fruits[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("the sorted array is:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        printf("%s\n", fruits[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```